# Passing data from a JSON array to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to pass data from one view controller such as the name and trying to display it in the next view controller but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using this [API](https://www.givefood.org.uk/api/2/foodbanks/) which is a JSON array to get the data for my app. I've looked all over for the answer to this but everything I try doesn't work. This is the code I'm using to try it right now but it doesn't work, this is in the first view controller

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {`
        if segue.identifier == "nextView" {
            if let name = sender as? String, let nextView = segue.destination as? ListViewController {
               nextView.nameText = name
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code in the destination view controller

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    
    var nameText: String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        name?.text = nameText
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @meaning-matters I want to click on a pin on the map and then the information for that pin be on the next page such as the name. I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The var you are trying to set in prepare `nameText` is a `String` so you should send it a `String` and not a `[jsonList]`

try like this :

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "view" {
        if let name = sender as? [jsonList], let nextView = segue.destination as! ListViewController {
            nextView.nameText = //change affectation here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll explain it a bit more, I have a map with pins and when clicked it goes to the next page. On the next page, it should say the name of the pin that was tapped. All the information for the places are in the API I linked in the original post. I've changed the original post to what you suggested but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try retrieving the name through the JSON you are using in your prepare function ? 
You can also check if the ```segue.identifier``` you provided is correct. If the name only isn't showing on the next view it seems to me that you are not getting the right value from the JSON.

Comment: Here is the function I'm using to get the JSON data https://pastebin.com/rw1Rdt5H and I've checked the `segue.identifier` and it is correct. Would I need to put the `override func prepare` in this block of code or outside? I've tried both and neither works.